# Bootstrap columns inside columns sizing issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pug

So I've used Bootstrap columns before, but this project requires some heavy nesting, and I can't get it to work.

The layout requires .col-8 and .col-4 when on desktop, no matter what. The 8 column will support two more columns inside of it that are evenly sized, in which some information will go. I've attached an example below to give an idea. Once the view hits mobile size, the 4 column will disappear and the little columns inside will take up the whole screen.

[image: So I'm trying to get a page to look like this.]

So I have

```
.container
  .row
    .col-md-8
      .row
        .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-lg-4
          | content
    .col-md-4
      .row
        .col-xs-12
          | content
```

This works for mobile. However, once you switch to tablet view, the two columns inside the `.col-md-8` will not line up next to each other, and I don't really understand why. If anyone can help me figure out where I'm going wrong I'd appreciate it. I haven't touched any of the code for columns, so it's still basic Bootstrap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I know what your issue is. I've read [this article](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works) (check out the section on nesting.) before and it mentions you only need rows on your outside most columns not on inner/nested ones.

So change it like this and it should work.

```
.container
  .row
    .col-md-8
      .col-xs-12.col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-lg-4
        | content
    .col-md-4
      .col-xs-12
        | content
```

Comment: YES thank you! I never saw that you didn't need rows on nested columns! While it's messed with the design of my stuff a little bit, it's an easy fix. Thank you so much!